# Python requests one element in list

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a question about the requests library in Python.

I tried to send this to my nodeJS server:

```
payload={
  "sid": _set["_id"],
  "pid": _project["_id"],
  "inputs": [_file["_id"]]  
}
print(payload)
response = requests.post(URLPORT+"/job/",headers={'Authorization': token},data=payload)
_job=response.json()
print(_job)
```

But what was recived is this (*console.log(req.body)*):

```
{ sid: '5a8862e8514580739235c0ab',
  pid: '5a9be32fdacc495d6a2ea8bf',
  inputs: '5a9be342dacc495d6a2ea8c0' }
```

If I send  `*"inputs": [_file["_id"],-1]*`  I get   `*inputs: [ '5a9be342dacc495d6a2ea8c0', '-1' ] }*`

Where are this both guys `**[** and **]**`, if I send only one element?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by, "Where are this both guys [ and ]"?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? Your code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Form-encoded data doesn't *do* lists. Were you trying to post JSON perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send a JSON body using requests, use the `json` argument instead of `data`. This works:

```
requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", json={"inputs": [1, 2, 3]})
```

Background:

`data` uses the request content type [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551320/9455968) which for a list with a single item is identical to a scalar item.

`json` uses the request content type `application/json` which serializes a dict/list structure to a JSON object.